# How to fix "invalid syntax for (>>>import datetime)"?

Tags: python, datetime

````
>>>import datetime
>>>now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>>print ("Current date and time : ") 
>>>print (now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%N:%S"))```
````

Error:

```
error: >>>import datetime
       ^
```

Comment: You should not paste an interpreter session into a .py file, would be my guess. `>>>` is the interactive prompt, it's **not** valid Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like that you have copied code from an interpreter or a book to a file and tried to run it with python command.
if you want to do so you need to remove `>>>` from lines and run again.

Comment: I done what you told me to do  but it shows new error .(Syntax Error: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement)

Comment: ok. what is the error?

Comment: (Syntax Error: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement)

Comment: for:(import datetime)

Comment: are you running this in a shell (interactive environment) or have you pasted the content in a .py file and running that file?

Comment: i tried it in  shell and visual studio but none of them works.

Comment: you get the same error in both? that's kind of wiered because this error seems to be for intractive env. I ran your code in my shell at got the proper response with no error.

Comment: no that error was from shell but in vs the error is different.It just says:(invalid syntax)

Comment: can you provide me with the exact code that you're using in vs?

Comment: happy to help :) this is what this community is all about ;)